# VS Code Error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm a bloody beginner in VS Code and in C (in fact I know nothing). But I have an aim. I want - one day - to be able to compile the C files from IAU SOFA. But before I have to learn how to compile. For this I installed the Mac clang compiler into VS Code (that I can use now for Python, too). I created four simple files: hellocopy.c, hello.c, myheader.h and tasks.json. I tell VS Code to compile 'with shift command B'.

I got the error:

> Starting build... /usr/bin/clang -g
> /Users/widmerhans/projects/Eigene_C_Programme/*.c
> /Users/widmerhans/projects/Eigene_C_Programme/Myheader/*.h -o
> /Users/widmerhans/projects/Eigene_C_Programme/hellocopy clang: error:
> cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files Build finished
> with error(s). The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).

**hellocopy.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myheader.h"

int main(){
    int age;
    printf("Enter age\n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("age is %d", age);
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

**hello.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myheader.h"

void hallo()  {
    printf("Hallo World\n");
}
```

**myheader.h:**

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

#define PI (3.1416)

// extern int meineVariable;

// extern int meineFunktion1(int);
// extern int meineFunktion2(char);

extern void hello();

#endif /* MYHEADER_H */
```

**tasks.json:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build C files",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}/*.c",
                "${fileDirname}/Myheader/*.h",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for the help.
Best Regards
Hans

Comment: When you edit your post, you can format some sections as code samples using the `{}` icon.

Comment: My recommendation with regards to multiple file compilation in VS Code is to graduate to a build system. Makefile support is now native, there's also CMake or meson or whatever. Then you can rely on the extension for the build system to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

Do not add header files to the compiler args. If you add header files, the compiler builds pre-compile headers and thus gets several additional output files for each header, but -o specifies a single output file.

Remove the line from "args"

```
"${fileDirname}/Myheader/*.h"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I put all files in one directory now and deleted the code row as you stated. And I got now the error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_hello", referenced from:
      _main in hellocopy-0e0359.o

Comment: You don't define the function "hello", you define the another function "hallo".

Comment: Thanks a lot S.M.! I'm also very bad in English. This was a mismatch between German and English. Wow, you did see it. Thanks, great. Hans

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd download and use the CMake extension in VS Code. You'll have to download CMake as well. Then set up your folders like this:

```
/project /* whatever you name it, home of CMakeLists.txt */
/project/build /* this is where you executable will be */
/project/include /*headers go in here */
/project/src /*source files go in here */
```

Then use this as your CMakeLists.txt file ...

```
// cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.3)
// project(TEMPLATE VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C)
// set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
// set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
// set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
// include_directories(include)
// file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.c")
// add_compile_options(-Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wpedantic)
// add_executable(TEMPLATE ${SOURCES})
// install(TARGETS TEMPLATE RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Just change the CMake version to what you have downloaded onto your system and change the word `TEMPLATE` to whatever you want to name your project (3 changes to make).

This way CMake manages everything for you and you can just focus on learning the C language. After you've installed the CMake extension and CMake itself you access the CMake commands in VS Code using ctrl shift p and typing CMake, ie: ctrl f5 to run debug, etc.

That's what I do to get projects going, and of course you can modify the CMakeLists.txt file as your projects grows, but that gets it going and enables use with YouCompleteMe in Vim, or whatever IDE you want to use that supports CMake (I use KDevelop and Vim). Here is a resource for CMake in VS Code on Linux: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux

Note: I had to use comments to post the contents of the CMakeLists.txt file on here, I don't post very many answers on here as I'm not much a C programmer, just a hobbyist. But this is what I do, it gets me coding ...

Edit: oh, I guess I should add - if you do it this way you don't have to worry about maintaining the various .JSON files that VS Code generates, everything is done through the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: LEF, thanks for the explanations about CMake. I think now I could dare to do what you recommended. I did read about CMake but I thought it is too complicated for a rookie like me. Regards, Hans